# Issue with WFFM 8.2 reCaptcha field on MVC Layout

Tags: wffm

I am trying to use WFFM reCaptcha field on one of my WFFM forms. The form is based on Sitecore MVC layout and using version 8.2 rev. 161129 (Update-1). I followed [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/web-forms-for-marketers/en/add-and-customize-a-recaptcha-field-on-mvc-layouts.html) guide and the reCaptcha field is showing. But when I try to submit the form, the form is giving the error that the captcha field is required.

I followed this [URL](http://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.com/2016/11/wffm-captcha-required-field-issue_58.html) to fix the issue, but I am getting another error as per the screenshot below. I don't have any server-side error in the log. Any help is really appreciated.

[image]